# RSA Key generation with SecKey Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, rsa, public-key

I'm trying to generate a public (and private) key pair using the SecKey class from Xamarin.iOS.
The KeySize is defined to 1024 bit and this seems to work (if I change this value, the length of the result array is changing too).

I generate the keys with

```
SecKey.GenerateKeyPair(CreateRsaParams(), out publicKey, out privateKey); 
byte[] key = publicKey.GetExternalRepresentation().ToArray()
```

(CreateRsaParams() is a function giving back a NSDictionary with the required data)

The problem is: I get a byte array (public key) with **140** Bytes - but depended on the key size it should have only 128 Byte - and I need a 128 Byte public key for data exchange with an other system

(by the way - using PCLCrypto is not an option for me since the project is not allowed to use this 3rd party component)

Does anyone know the problem and know a solution?

Comment: Refer this blog https://msicc.net/tag/rsa/

Comment: Thanks Lucas for the link. I already used most of the code from this blog. Now I changed completely to this code and use the key chain - but the result is the same 140 byte key. So the problem isn't solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved.
If anyone is facing the same problem, you can find the solution at
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111109

The problem was not the key, but the wrongly formulated requirement.